# Change other input field value by changing Increment/decrement value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a increment decrement input field and i want to change value of other input text field by by plus and minus value. let suppose if value is selected from increment decrement input field then the other text field value appears 100 and if value select 2 then other field value appears 200 and so on. so far i just create a increment decrement field. don't know how to do next. please help me on this problem and forgive me about this because i'm and still learning.

this is just simple plus/minus input field

Comment: i'm trying sir so for i created plus/minus input field. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/b2dacy4e/#&togetherjs=ISRvGwrE3o

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered your JSFiddle to help you out here. You simply needed to add a new method to calculate the new value (100 * count) and assign that value to the appropriate input box, and then call that method from your plus and minus methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/jebcnvwd/

```
var count = 1;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");

function plus() {
  count++;
  countEl.value = count;
  calculateResult(count);
}

function minus() {
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
    calculateResult(count);
  }
}

function calculateResult(count) {
  var resultInt = count * 100;
  var resultInput = document.getElementById("result");
  resultInput.value = resultInt;
}

calculateResult(count);
```

Comment: function is perfectly working in jsfiddle but not in my compiler i'm using sublime text. what should i do ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the whole project. Is the javascript inside of the HTML document or inside a separate file? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Working fine now. the id= result was causing problem actually  there are multiple id's with same name.